# Bootcamp windows drivers downloading stuck

Tags: macos, bootcamp

This is my fourth download, Net speed 12MBPS and everytime its stuck at this place. How can fix this.

I am running Mountain Lion on 128GB SSD, 8GB Ram with Mid 2010 model.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try getting your drivers from here: [Bootcamp Drivers (Apple.com)](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/downloads/) Tell me if it works better here! Apples servers hang up a lot and I am not sure why. It may also help to try downloading while using ethernet rather than wireless just in case it is your router/AP.